# How to retrieve multidimensional data from CSV file?

Tags: r

I have a large csv file in the following form:

```
Linac,Equipment,Energy,Date,Initial,Adjusted
Acacia,MPC,6x,02/08/17 17:14:19,0.12,#N/A
Acacia,MPC,10x,02/08/17 17:17:28,-0.09,#N/A
Acacia,MPC,6FFF,02/08/17 17:17:35,-0.29,#N/A
Acacia,MPC,6e,02/08/17 17:17:35,-0.07,#N/A
Acacia,MPC,9e,02/08/17 17:17:37,-0.15,#N/A
...
```

The fields Linac, Equipment, and Energy can only take a small set of possible values each.

I would like to work with subsets of the data - something like `allData[Acacia,MPC,6x]`. How can I do this?

My code so far:

```
> allData <- read.csv(file="AllData.csv")
> allData["Acacia"]
Error in `[.data.frame`(allData, "Acacia") : undefined columns selected
```

Comment: `subset(allData, Linac == 'Acacia' & Equipment == 'MPC' & Energy == '6x')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
subData <- subset(allData, Linac == "Acacia" & Equipment == "MPC" & Energy == "6x")
```

or

```
subData <- allData[allData$Linac == "Acacia" & allData$ Equipment == "MPC" & allData$Energy == "6x", ]
```